# Baking/Endorsing Rights

Tags: node, baking, baker, solo-baking

How are baking and endorsement rights allocated to bakers? Is there a formula? Can we see the distribution of the baking/endorsement rights for all bakers for each cycle? (Particularly for priority 0)

Answer (score 2):

Baking and endorsing rights are allocated at random, proportionally to the delegate's stake, using a PRNG and a random seed derived from on-chain data (nonces committed by bakers and revealed later). For more details, see the [doc](http://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html).

To see the distribution of baking/endorsing rights, use these RPCs:

- https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-helpers-baking-rights
- https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-helpers-endorsing-rights

Comment: Could a block explorer show the aforementioned randomness by listing the priority 0 baking rights of bakers per cycle?

Comment: So you would like to see the random seed used to allocate the baking rights?

Or just to see who are the bakers at priority 0?

Comment: Both...we see which bakers are baking blocks as it happens, but can this info be scraped and presented in advance?

Comment: To get the seed for the current cycle:
`tezos-client rpc post /chains/main/blocks/head/context/seed` (though I don't see what would you use it for...)
To get the the bakers at priority 0 for cycle `x`: `tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/baking_rights?cycle=x&max_priority=1`